# How can I best protect myself on an encrypted network with untrustworthy users?

Tags: encryption, wifi, printers

I will be starting university in September. As part of my accommodation I will be provided with fast WiFi which requires a password to connect to (WPA2 Enterprise).

However, I don't trust the other users on the network. How can I protect myself on my phone and laptop from any potential security risks this situation arises? And how can I protect my printer from being publicly accessible?

Comment: use a VPN so there are no other users

Comment: Use only secure protocols. If you printer does not support them, then create a private physical network. You can connect to the outside world by using a vpn, or at least only using https.

Answer (score 1):

Buy your own hotspot from a provider for your laptop.

Using university wifi gives them the right to monitor what you do and say on the web. As you pointed out, it also exposes you to potential bad actors.

Comment: How can I get internet? I won't have my own landline. I'm not concerned about the providers of the WiFi - I'm concerned about the other users